# NiceGUI Python tabs

Tags: python, tabs, nicegui

How make tabs in tabs with NiceGUI?

```
from nicegui import ui

with ui.tabs().classes('w-full') as tabs:
    one = ui.tab('One')
    two = ui.tab('Two')
with ui.tab_panels(tabs, value=two).classes('w-full'):
    with ui.tab_panel(one):
        ui.label('First tab')
    with ui.tab_panel(two):
        with ui.tabs().classes('w-full') as db_tabs:
            db_one = ui.tab('db_one')
            db_two = ui.tab('db_two')
        with ui.tab_panels(db_tabs, value=db_one).classes('w-full'):
            with ui.tab_panel(db_one):
                ui.label('First tab')
            with ui.tab_panel(db_two):
                ui.label('First tab')
ui.run()
```

How to make another tab bar on one of the main tabs using NiceGUI?

Comment: What is wrong with the solution you posted? What did you expect or what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you found the answer or not. But I came across this question looking for an answer.

Not sure I understand the ask. But if you want to make one the default tab this is how.

```
from nicegui import ui
with ui.tabs().classes('w-full') as tabs:
    one = ui.tab('One')
    two = ui.tab('Two')
with ui.tab_panels(tabs, value=<replace with tab panel you want to be default>).classes('w-full'):
    with ui.tab_panel(one):
        ui.label('First tab')
    with ui.tab_panel(two):
        with ui.tabs().classes('w-full') as db_tabs:
            db_one = ui.tab('db_one')
            db_two = ui.tab('db_two')
        with ui.tab_panels(db_tabs, value=db_one).classes('w-full'):
            with ui.tab_panel(db_one):
                ui.label('First tab')
            with ui.tab_panel(db_two):
                ui.label('First tab')
ui.run()
```